# Create legend for plot with mulitple normal distributions

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a plot with mulitple normal distributions using the `mapply` and `stat_fuction` function in ggplot. I have assigned each line a unique color and line type (dashed or solid), but I have not figured out how to include a legend in the figure. This is my first time using the `stat_function` in ggplot and an completely lost on how this function talks with the aesthetic mapping funtion (`aes`) to create the legend. The code below will produce the figure without the legend, but has my attempt at producing the legend. I need the legend to show both the color and line type (dashed or solid) for each normal distribution.

Any assitance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0.707, 0.757)), aes(x = x)) +
  
  mapply(function(mean, sd, col, lty, reg) {
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), aes(colour = reg), col = col, lty = lty, lwd = 1.5)
  }, 
  # mean, sd, col, lty
  mean = c(0.7092, 0.711533333, 0.72675, 0.726566667, 0.7253, 0.7467, 0.7356, 0.7356, 0.7332, 0.7393, 0.7321, 0.737533333, 0.7162, 0.7201, 0.7247,
           0.724, 0.7289, 0.728657143, 0.7306, 0.7306),
  
  sd = c(0.000381708, 0.000381708, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.000381708, 0.000696549, 0.001557951, 0.001827967,
         0.001557951, 0.002658488, 0.001827967, 0.001827967, 0.002968083, 0.001557951, 0.001266277, 0.001051011, 0.001842546, 0.001842546),
  
  reg = c("R1", "R2", "R3.1", "R3.2", "R3.3", "R4", "R5.1", "R5.2", "R6.1", "R6.2", "R6.3", "R6.4", 
            "R7.1", "R7.2", "R8.1", "R8.2", "R9.1", "R9.2", "R10.1", "R10.2"),
  
  col = c("black", "red", "gray38", "gray58", "gray78", "darkblue", "chartreuse", "chartreuse4", "gold", "gold3", "goldenrod1", "goldenrod3",
          "deepskyblue", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid", "darkorchid1", "darkolivegreen", "darkolivegreen3", "hotpink", "hotpink3"),
  
  lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))

p1 + scale_colour_manual(name = "Regions",
                        
                        values = c("black", "red", "gray38", "gray58", "gray78", "darkblue", "chartreuse", "chartreuse4", "gold", "gold3", "goldenrod1", "goldenrod3",
                                 "deepskyblue", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid", "darkorchid1", "darkolivegreen", "darkolivegreen3", "hotpink", "hotpink3"), 
                        
                        breaks = c("R1", "R2", "R3.1", "R3.2", "R3.3", "R4", "R5.1", "R5.2", "R6.1", "R6.2", "R6.3", "R6.4", 
                                   "R7.1", "R7.2", "R8.1", "R8.2", "R9.1", "R9.2", "R10.1", "R10.2"),
                        
                         labels = c("1", "2", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "4", "5.1", "5.2", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", "6.4", 
                                 "7.1", "7.2", "8.1", "8.2", "9.1", "9.2", "10.1", "10.2"))

p1 + scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)) 
  
p1 + theme(legend.position="top")

p1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very small change 1. removed col = col from third line 2. assigned changes to `p1` whenever change is made.

Code will look like:

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = c(0.707, 0.757)), aes(x = x)) +
  
  mapply(function(mean, sd, col, lty, reg) {
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), aes(colour = reg), lty = lty, lwd = 1.5)
  }, 
  # mean, sd, col, lty
  mean = c(0.7092, 0.711533333, 0.72675, 0.726566667, 0.7253, 0.7467, 0.7356, 0.7356, 0.7332, 0.7393, 0.7321, 0.737533333, 0.7162, 0.7201, 0.7247,
           0.724, 0.7289, 0.728657143, 0.7306, 0.7306),
  
  sd = c(0.000381708, 0.000381708, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.001557951, 0.000381708, 0.000696549, 0.001557951, 0.001827967,
         0.001557951, 0.002658488, 0.001827967, 0.001827967, 0.002968083, 0.001557951, 0.001266277, 0.001051011, 0.001842546, 0.001842546),
  
  reg = c("R1", "R2", "R3.1", "R3.2", "R3.3", "R4", "R5.1", "R5.2", "R6.1", "R6.2", "R6.3", "R6.4", 
          "R7.1", "R7.2", "R8.1", "R8.2", "R9.1", "R9.2", "R10.1", "R10.2"),
  
  col = c("black", "red", "gray38", "gray58", "gray78", "darkblue", "chartreuse", "chartreuse4", "gold", "gold3", "goldenrod1", "goldenrod3",
          "deepskyblue", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid", "darkorchid1", "darkolivegreen", "darkolivegreen3", "hotpink", "hotpink3"),
  
  lty = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2))


p1 = p1 + scale_colour_manual(name = "Regions",
                         
                         values = c("black", "red", "gray38", "gray58", "gray78", "darkblue", "chartreuse", "chartreuse4", "gold", "gold3", "goldenrod1", "goldenrod3",
                                    "deepskyblue", "deepskyblue3", "darkorchid", "darkorchid1", "darkolivegreen", "darkolivegreen3", "hotpink", "hotpink3"), 
                         
                         breaks = c("R1", "R2", "R3.1", "R3.2", "R3.3", "R4", "R5.1", "R5.2", "R6.1", "R6.2", "R6.3", "R6.4", 
                                    "R7.1", "R7.2", "R8.1", "R8.2", "R9.1", "R9.2", "R10.1", "R10.2"),
                         
                         labels = c("1", "2", "3.1", "3.2", "3.3", "4", "5.1", "5.2", "6.1", "6.2", "6.3", "6.4", 
                                    "7.1", "7.2", "8.1", "8.2", "9.1", "9.2", "10.1", "10.2"))

p1 = p1 + scale_linetype_manual(values = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)) 

p1 = p1 + theme(legend.position="top")

p1
```

Comment: you are a legend! Thanks for your time. Take care.